# ExcelMapper C# set a column to be a hyperlink?

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core

I'm using the ExcelMapper library
https://github.com/mganss/ExcelMapper

However, I'm stuck on one part - I'm trying to set a cell value to be a hyperlink.

I've tried the following:

```
var data = new List<rows>();
-- Snip code
data.Row[0] = "=HYPERLINK(\"" + url.ActionLink("Action", "Controller", new { Id = obj.Id }) +"\")";

-- snip code

var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var excelMapper = new ExcelMapper();

            excelMapper.Saving += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Sheet.AutoSizeColumn(0);

                e.Sheet.ForceFormulaRecalculation = true;
            };


            await excelMapper.SaveAsync(ms, data);
```

I was hoping the `ForceFormulaRecalculation` would make the formula calculate, but sadly not...

I've also decorated the property with `[FormulaResult]` as per here: https://github.com/mganss/ExcelMapper#map-formulas-or-results

Is there a way to set this up?